# Change Highmaps map colour

Tags: colors, background, highmaps

I want to be able to change the colour of this exact entire map. I am using map bubble I want a darker color for the countries and continents. how can i achieve this as colorAxis will change the data representation(bubble) colour not the map colour.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-bubble/

apparently this does not work :(

```
colorAxis : {
  color: 'red'  
},
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try replacing **color** property with **nullColor**. What it does is changing the color of all shapes to red.

Please check my fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0e910h2v/)

```
{
    name: 'Countries',
    mapData: mapData,
    //color: '#E0E0E0',
    nullColor: 'red',
    enableMouseTracking: false
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can I set many colors for null value? For example: if the country is Vietnam, it should be pink, while other null countries is red.

Comment: yes, check the documentation, they have examples for this